# Primeng custom filter using p-calendar throws error: Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Tags: angular, date, calendar, filtering, primeng-datatable

I'm trying to filter a table by dates, using p calendar. it all works when I have a single entry.
The first issue is that the range does not appear on the calendar when selected, but the filter works fine.
here is the table with no filter applied
[image]

here is the table filtered on dates Sept 5th - Sept 7th
[image]

the selected date range shows on reopening the filterbox AFTER filtering:
[image]

As you can see, this is what appears after clearing the filter to display the whole data

The second issue is that I get the following errors when selecting dates:
[image]

here is the code:

table.component.ts:
[image]

table.component.html:
[image]

I tried removing the `[(ngModel)] = rangeDates` from the p-calendar element in tht html (which made the selected range of dates appear at the right time, before applying the filter) but then, the filter wouldn't work on the table.